# Finding google account a Client ID associated with

Tags: google-api

I have the client ID and client secret for my oAuth App. Unfortunately, I am not sure which google account we used to create that app. Is there a way to find what google account is a client ID associated with?

Comment: probably best to contact Google directly.

Comment: Okay thanks Bryant